# Hibernate doesn't create one entity

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-mvc

I'm trying to create tables using hibernate but all the entities seems to be mapped as tables except for one. Even the manytomany containing this table's id is created but not the table itself.

**Service.java**

```
@Entity
@Table(name="service")
public class Service {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name="id")
    private int id;

    @Column(name="title")
    private String title;

    @Column(name="description")
    private String desc;

    @Column(name="price")
    private int price;

    @Column(name="limit")
    private int limit;

    @Column(name="status")
    private boolean available;

    @Column(name="tags")
    private String tags;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name="provider_id")
    private User provider;

    @ManyToOne(cascade = {CascadeType.DETACH,CascadeType.MERGE,CascadeType.PERSIST,CascadeType.REFRESH})
    @JoinColumn(name="category_id")
    private Category category;

    @ManyToMany(cascade = {CascadeType.DETACH,CascadeType.MERGE,CascadeType.PERSIST,CascadeType.REFRESH})
    @JoinTable(
            name="service_clients",
            joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name="service_id"),
            inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name="client_id")
    )
    private List<User> clients;
    //GETTERS,SETTERS
}
```

I can update the post if you need more information.

PS: I don't get any error in my logs.

Comment: Have you tried renaming the table to something else than "service"? ... maybe service is a reserved keyword.

Comment: https://vladmihalcea.com/hibernate-hbm2ddl-auto-schema/

Comment: Already have Auto schema , also i need to edit my post cause i indeed found an error in my log : GenerationTarget encountered exception accepting command : Error executing DDL via JDBC Statement

Comment: Also i already tried renaming the table

Comment: Can you post the full error message ?

Comment: Found the error i had a column named "limit" which is a reserved word

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"limit" is reserved keyword for some databases. You can change the name of the property or you can create the table manualy.

Answer (score 0):

On top of Buraks awnser, you could try encoding the column name:

```
    @Column(name="\"limit\"")
```

Unfortunatly Hibernate isn't doing this by itself, for many vendors and keywords (like "order", "user") it's needed.